# Doctrine Batch Processing Iterate High Memory Usage

Tags: doctrine, batch-processing

I've been looking into using iterators for batch processing in Doctrine (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html). I've got a database with 20,000 images which I would like to iterate over.

I understand that using an iterator is supposed to prevent Doctrine from loading every row in memory. However the memory usage between the two examples is almost exactly the same. I am calculating the memory usage before and after using `(memory_get_usage() / 1024)`.

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT i FROM Acme\Entities\Image i');
$iterable = $query->iterate();

while (($image = $iterable->next()) !== false) {
    // Do something here!
}
```

Memory usage for the iterator.

```
Memory usage before: 2823.36328125 KB
Memory usage after: 50965.3125 KB
```

This second example loads the entire result set into memory using the `findAll` method.

```
$images = $this->em->getRepository('Acme\Entities\Image')->findAll();
```

Memory usage for `findAll`.

```
Memory usage before: 2822.828125 KB
Memory usage after: 51329.03125 KB
```

Answer (score 76):

Batch processing with doctrine is trickier than it seems, even with the help of `iterate()` and `IterableResult`.

Just as you expected greatest benefit of `IterableResult` is that it does not load all of the elements into memory, and the second benefit is that it doesn't hold references to the entities you load, thus `IterableResult` doesn't prevent GC from freeing memory from your entity.

However there's another object Doctrine's `EntityManager` (more specifically `UnitOfWork`) which holds all the references to each object which you queried explicitly or implicitly (`EAGER` associations).

In simple words, whenever you get any entity(ies) returned by `findAll()` `findOneBy()` even through `DQL` queries and also `IterableResult`, then a reference to each of those entities is saved inside of doctrine. The reference is simply stored in an assoc array, here's pseudocode:
`$identityMap['Acme\Entities\Image'][0] = $image0;`

So because upon each iteration of your loop, your previous images (despite not being present in the loop's scope or `IterableResult`'s scope) are still present inside of this `identityMap`, GC cannot clean them and your memory consumption is the same as when you were calling `findAll()`.

Now let's go through the code and see what is actually happening

```php
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT i FROM Acme\Entities\Image i');  
// here doctrine only creates Query object, no db access here

$iterable = $query->iterate();
// unlike findAll(), upon this call no db access happens.  
// Here the Query object is simply wrapped in an Iterator  

while (($image_row = $iterable->next()) !== false) {  
    // now upon the first call to next() the DB WILL BE ACCESSED FOR THE FIRST TIME
    // the first resulting row will be returned
    // row will be hydrated into Image object
    // ----> REFERENCE OF OBJECT WILL BE SAVED INSIDE $identityMap <----
    // the row will be returned to you via next()

    // to access actual Image object, you need to take [0]th element of the array                            


     $image = $image_row[0];
    // Do something here!
     write_image_data_to_file($image,'myimage.data.bin');
    
    //now as the loop ends, the variables $image (and $image_row) will go out of scope 
    // and from what we see should be ready for GC
    // however because reference to this specific image object is still held
    // by the EntityManager (inside of $identityMap), GC will NOT clean it 
}
// and by the end of your loop you will consume as much memory
// as you would have by using `findAll()`.
```

So the first solution is to actually tell Doctrine EntityManager to detach the object from the `$identityMap`.  I also replaced `while` loop to `foreach` to make it more readable.

```php
foreach($iterable as $image_row){
    $image = $image_row[0]; 

    // do something with the image
    write_image_data_to_file($image);
    
    $entity_manager->detach($image);
    // this line will tell doctrine to remove the _reference_to_the_object_ 
    // from identity map. And thus object will be ready for GC
}
```

However the example above has few flaws, even though it is featured in the [doctrine's documentation on batch processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing). It works well, in case your entity `Image` isn't performing `EAGER` load for any of it's associations. But if you're EAGERly loading any of the associations eg. :

```php
/*
  @ORM\Entity
*/
class Image {
  
  /* 
    @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    @ORM\Id 
   */
  private $id;
  
  /*
    @ORM\Column(type="string")
  */
  private $imageName;

  /*
   @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
   This association will be automatically (EAGERly) loaded by doctrine
   every time you query from db Image entity. Whether by findXXX(),DQL or iterate()
  */
  private $owner;

  // getters/setters left out for clarity
}
```

So if we use same piece of the code as above, upon

```php
foreach($iterable as $image_row){
    $image = $image_row[0]; 
    // here becuase of EAGER loading, we already have in memory owner entity
    // which can be accessed via $image->getOwner() 

    // do something with the image
    write_image_data_to_file($image);
    
    $entity_manager->detach($image);
    // here we detach Image entity, but `$owner` `User` entity is still
    // referenced in the doctrine's `$identityMap`. Thus we are leaking memory still.
   
}
```

The possible solution can be to use `EntityManager::clear()` instead or `EntityManager::detach()` which will clear COMPLETELY the identity map.

```php
foreach($iterable as $image_row){
    $image = $image_row[0]; 
    // here becuase of EAGER loading, we already have in memory owner entity
    // which can be accessed via $image->getOwner() 

    // do something with the image
    write_image_data_to_file($image);
    
    $entity_manager->clear();
    // now ``$identityMap` will be cleared of ALL entities it has
    // the `Image` the `User` loaded in this loop iteration and as as
    // SIDE EFFECT all OTHER Entities which may have been loaded by you
    // earlier. Thus you when you start this loop you must NOT rely
    // on any entities you have `persist()`ed or `remove()`ed 
    // all changes since the last `flush()` will be lost.
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I will add from my experence, that `$iterable = $query->iterate();` can consume tons of memory as well because of query buffering. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: @dimitri_k Thank you for details, btw is there a way to use HYDRATE_SCALAR with iterator ? If yes then would that be another alternative to deal with this `identityMap` issue ?

Comment: @Stphane that's an interesting suggestion to use HYDRATE_SCALAR. Originally I didn't think of it as viable option because when you use  HYDRATE_SCALAR - you wouldn't get objects returned in a nice traversable object graph. You will NOT be able to follow relationship from one object to another like in `$image->getUser()->getProfession()->getSalary()`.  They would be returned as big union array (akin to `SELECT ... JOIN`).   HYDRATE_SCALAR may work for you when you have flat object relationships (1 or 2 levels). I am not sure how it works when you have more relationships added to object later...

Comment: But I looked at the Doctrine source and `ArrayHydrator` doesn't seem to be calling `$this->registerManaged(..)`. Which probably means that you shouldn't be getting memory leaks.  https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ArrayHydrator.php

Comment: `Unlike findAll(), upon this call no db access happens`


Completely **false** statement. The data is fully fetched but hydrated row-by-row. See the code in @BlocksByLukas's answer.

Comment: thank you @SalmanvonAbbas for being so scrupulous to my post.  From what I remember from 5 yrs ago when I wrote it, the problem was `getIterator() / iterate()` method within ORM classes (couldn't quickly find which file it was).  Which had lazy implementation. Whereas the answer of @BlocksByLukas you've referred to shows implementation not of ORM, but of the underlying driver of mysqli `namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement` (and it uses SQL not DQL). `MysqliStatement` is part of Doctrine project (as a driver but not ORM).  That's what I can remember off the top of my head...

Comment: @SalmanvonAbbas also the point i was trying to make with call to `->iterate()` was that it simply returns wrapper object (there's no actual physical request to mysql or mysql driver made yet). And only upon _request of first item from iterator_ that process of query is initiated. (Thus this behaviour doesn't contradict with what @BlocksByLukas stated, assuming his research results were right and apply here). ps. also in my previous comment i mistakenly mentioned two methods `getIterator()/ iterate()`, but it should correctly read only one `iterate()`  (can't edit that comment anymore).

Comment: 'detach' is deprecated.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko so I wonder what's the new approach? From ([Doctrine Docs about Batch processing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)) we can read the following `An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions. Every RDBMS has its own, most effective way of dealing with such operations......`  seems that the answer is : "Do not use Doctrine for batch processing" :S   You can also find this [Doctrine Issue on Deprecation of EntityRepository#clear()](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7922) helpful

Comment: At least we do want to use it for batch select (many thousands of nested entities). EntityManager::clear() seems to do the job BUT it still wastes a lot of CPU time on this cache nonsense. I'm generally displeased with Doctrine intenal sloppiness. @DimitryK If you want a job to be done properly, do it yourself ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you combine doctrine `iterate()` with batching strategy, you should be able to iterate over large records.

For example:

```php
$batchSize = 1000;
$numberOfRecordsPerPage = 5000;

$totalRecords = $queryBuilder->select('count(u.id)')
            ->from('SELECT i FROM Acme\Entities\Image i')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();   //Get total records to iterate on

        $totalProcessed = 0;

        $processing = true;

        while ($processing) {
            $query = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT i FROM Acme\Entities\Image i')
                ->setMaxResults($numberOfRecordsPerPage) //Maximum records to fetch at a time
                ->setFirstResult($totalProcessed);
          
             $iterableResult = $query->iterate();
          
            while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
                $image = $row[0];
                $image->updateSomethingImportant();
              
                 if (($totalProcessed % $batchSize ) === 0) {
                    $entityManager->flush();
                    $entityManager->clear();
                }
                $totalProcessed++;
            }
            if ($totalProcessed === $totalRecords) {
                break;
            }
        }

    $entityManager->flush();
```

See [Iterating large data in doctrine 2](https://hubofco.de/php/2019/04/19/how-to-update-millions-of-records-with-doctrine-orm/)

Comment: Iterate should be enough. Maybe he should disable doctrine cache ?

Answer (score 5):

I strongly believe the batch processing with Doctrine or any kind of iterations with MySQL (PDO or mysqli) are just an illusion.

@dimitri-k provided a nice explanation especially about unit of work. The problem is the miss leading: "**$query->iterate()**" which doesn't really iterate over the data source. It's **just an \Traversable wrapper** around already **fully fetched** data source.

An example demonstrating that even removing Doctrine abstraction layer completely from the picture, we will still run into **memory issues**:

```
echo 'Starting with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";

$pdo  = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=HOST", "USER", "PW");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_big_table LIMIT 100000');
$stmt->execute();

while ($rawCampaign = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // echo $rawCampaign['id'] . "\n";
}

echo 'Ending with memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024 . " MB \n";
```

**Output:**

```
Starting with memory usage: 6 MB 
Ending with memory usage: 109.46875 MB
```

Here, the disappointing **getIterator()** method:

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    $data = $this->fetchAll();

    return new \ArrayIterator($data);
}
```

You can use my little library to **actually** stream heavy tables using PHP Doctrine or DQL or just pure SQL. However you find appropriate: https://github.com/EnchanterIO/remote-collection-stream

Comment: you didn't explain why your library is better tho

Comment: @EnchanterIO How does your library improve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36201665

Comment: Thank you @blocksbylukas for the interesting idea, but I don't have time now to understand it properly, as I don't use Doctrine that much anymore.

Comment: I think you are wrong regarding batch processing and Doctrine, at least nowadays. It is not simply an array iterator over already fetched data. I was just able to reduce the memory consumption alot by implementing the iterator pattern as outlined by others and in the docs.

Comment: But what kind of queries happened behind the scenes? How much data did you fetch in memory? Surely Doctrine is doing some fantastic tricks and I don't remember exactly what was the issue 3 years ago but I think I wrote this answer because I was under the premise that the Iterator is going to somehow "stream" the rows from a table, and I believe it instead fetched all the rows and THEN did PHP optimization on Entities. It's probably different now, 3 years later. That little library (didn't use it since then honestly) is just very explicit about what it does: SQL Offsets + Iterator for looping.

Comment: Oh I miss PHP! Feeling nostalgic now, this was one of the last things I did in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr;

When running the command use `--no-debug` or set the **Sql logger to null** to prevent it saving all queries it runs.

Every then and now use `EntityManager::clear()`, memory leak will go down to almost zero.

Answer (score 2):

For batching I like to use `yield` this way:

**ImageRepository.php**

```php
<?php

class ImageRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    // The rest of your code...

    public function findAllImages(): \Iterator
    {
        // Find the total amount of images.
        $total_images = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
           ->select('COUNT(*)')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getSingleScalarResult();

        $processed_records = 0;

        while (true) {
            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
                // Process batch of 100 results, this can
                // be whatever amount you can fit in memory,
                ->setMaxResults(100)
                ->setFirstResult($processed_records)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

            $processed_records += count($query);

            // With yield you are not storing the full
            // amount of images in memory.    
            yield from $query;

            if ($processed_records >= $total_images) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it somewhere

```php
<?php

class ImageCommand extends Command
{
    // The rest of your code...

    public function processAllImages(ImageRepository $repository): void
    {
        $images = $repository->findAllImages();

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $this->processImage($image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

The results could be similar because the db client may be allocating additional memory you cant see. Also your code uses the 'IterableResult' which is returned form '$query->iterate()'; this allows for processing large results without memory problems. Just quick thoughts hope it helped a little.

Comment: This answer does not help at all.